# Issue processing a servlet call after a confirm box call in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, confirm

Still working on my mainEFT.jsp and I was trying to add a confirmation box that checks whether the user wants to not enter values in the command line and select all records.  If they click “OK” then it should process all records.  If they click “Cancel” they get another message and go back to command line.   Here is the code inside the ‘document).ready(function)’ section:

```
    $("#searchEFT").mousedown(function ()
        {

          var Cmd_Sched_Number = document.getElementById("CMDScheduleNumber").value;
          var Cmd_Contract_Year = document.getElementById("CMDContractYear").value;
          var Cmd_Status = document.getElementById("CMDSchedStatus").value;
          var Cmd_Creation_Date = document.getElementById("CMDCreationDate").value;

          if (Cmd_Sched_Number == "") 
          {
              if (Cmd_Contract_Year != "") {
                  alert("Schedule Number and EFT Contract Year must be both populated");
                  return false;
              }
          } 
          else if (Cmd_Contract_Year == "") 
          {
                alert("Schedule Number and EFT Contract year must be both populated");
                return false;
          }

          if (Cmd_Status == " " && Cmd_Creation_Date == "" &&
              Cmd_Sched_Number == "" && Cmd_Contract_Year == "")
          {
              if (confirm("Are you sure you want to pull all EFT schedule numbers?") == false) 
                 {
                   alert("Please enter information in any of the command line fields") ;
                   return false ;
                 } 
             else
                {
                  return true ;
                }                
           }

     });
```

Here is the code for the button that calls the EFTscreen.java program:

```
        <button id="searchEFT" type="submit" formaction="EFTscreen?action=searchEFT" 
                        class="btn smBtn">Search</button>
```

When I am clicking OK the program isn’t going to my EFTscreen.java program and continue processing.  Is this an issue with using a confirm box that stops processing, or something else?  I am thinking I need something on the return but not sure.  I am getting to my EFTscreen.java program when I have data in any of those fields.

Thanks

Comment: I modified the code to put 'return false' or 'return true' and didn't seem to do much.  I am guessing I have to do something with the button but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer was not correct. I misread your question. Now that i see it again, the problem in your code lies in the fact that you are having a "submit" button with a mousedown handler the same time. For your code to work you must have something like the following:

```
<form id="myform" method="get" action="EFTscreen?action=searchEFT">
    ..... Various controls in for (text - checkboxes - dropdowns)
    <button id="searchEFT">Search</button>
</form>
```

(Note that in my code the button is NOT type="submit")

Then add your mouse hanlder as above but instead of returning true you have to submit the form:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

UPDATE:
How this works now? Well, you enclose your data to be submitted in the `form` element. The `form` element defines what inputs(data) will be submitted using the `GET` or `POST` method defined in the `action` attribute of the form. This will eventually trigger the servlet's `doGet` or `doPost` methods.

Now, by removing the `type=submit` from our button we prevent the automatic submission of the form. By adding also the event handler on our button, we are able to execute some javascript when the button is clicked. The same could be achieved by `<button id=".." onclick="myFunction();">`

And finaly the thing that submits the form is actually the check inside out javascript form check.

Hope that was helpfull

Comment: Well what is the difference between using 'mousedown" or "click" or even a "mouseup" which I have seen a few times?

Comment: That worked.  I had to change my method to 'POST' but it did get to the servlet code.  I still don't understand why we had to put the formaction stuff in the <form> when we hit the confirm box but not in any other scenario.   Thanks

Comment: The POST and GET depends on which method you implemented in the servlet (doGet or doPost). I will update my answer to make it clearer what we do here